# Are interest bearing checking accounts (rewards checking) covered by FDIC?

Tags: interest-rate, portfolio, fdic

I see a lot of banks offering rewards checking accounts (maintain the account in an active status by doing x transactions/month,direct deposit, paper less statements etc, in return you yearn high apy. apy varies month to month)

I see a few of them here

http://www.depositaccounts.com/checking/reward-checking-accounts.html

http://www.bestcashcow.com/bank_rates/best_reward_checking_account_rates.html

Are interest bearing rewards checking account FDIC insured ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any type of [Deposit Account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposit_account) is insured, while any investment is not covered.

Accounts in banks are insured by the [FDIC](http://www.fdic.gov/consumers/consumer/information/fdiciorn.html), accounts in credit unions are insured by the [NCUA](http://www.ncua.gov/resources/shareinsurance/ncuainsurancefundfaqs.htm)